# R convert different date variables

Tags: r, date

I have one variable with variisu date formats:

2016-05-02T11:20:00
or
4/25/2016 4:48:00 AM

Is there a good function that can intepret different date formats in one swoop and convert to the same format?

I previously just used

```
strptime(Data$Date, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

For the format of 2016-05-02T11:20:00

Is there a better way before considering an ifelse or something?

Comment: functions in the lubridate package are very friendly, but assume that all dates have the same format. Perhaps you could use grep to identify the rows with a specific format and send these to the appropriate lubridate function one format at a time.

Comment: `lubridate::parse_date_time` might be useful.

Comment: Just saw that elsewhere,looks like it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, as seen in comments, lubridate::parse_date_time worked well.

parse_date_time(Data$DateVariable, orders=c("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S","%m/%d/%y %H/%M/%S"))